# FaultException not being handled by server on callback made call

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, faultexception, communicationexception

I have a situation where the server requests information from the client.

Callback declaration:

```
public interface IControlServiceCallback
{
    [...]

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(GetSystemFilesFault))]
    List<SystemFile> GetSystemFiles(string directory);
}
```

Callback implementation:

```
public List<SystemFile> GetSystemFiles(string directory)
{
    try
    {
        var files = Directory.GetDirectories(directory)
                             .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x))
                             .Select(x => new SystemFile(x)).ToList();

        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(directory)
                                .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                                .Select(x => new SystemFile(x)));

        return files;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        throw new FaultException<GetSystemFilesFault>(new GetSystemFilesFault(e));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new FaultException<GetSystemFilesFault>(new GetSystemFilesFault(e));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I make the call do the method and it throws a `FaultException<TDetail>` on the client side, the exception in not handled correctly. I get a `CommunicationException` instead. As illustrated bellow.

[image]

I tried to use some WCF logging functionality to see if I could isolate the problem, but the exception is being thrown as soon as the server receives the response.

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at RemoteControl.Service.IControlServiceCallback.GetSystemFiles(String directory)
   at RemoteControl.Service.Objects.Handling.ControlServiceCallbackProxy.GetSystemFiles(String directory) in c:\Users\Bruno\Source\Repos\RemoteControl\RemoteControl\RemoteControl.Service\Objects\Handling\ControlServiceCallbackProxy.cs:line 46
   at RemoteControl.Host.Controllers.ClientController.SelectedDirectoryChanged(String path) in c:\Users\Bruno\Source\Repos\RemoteControl\RemoteControl\RemoteControl.Host\Controllers\ClientController.cs:line 41
   at RemoteControl.Host.Forms.ClientForm.treeList_DoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Bruno\Source\Repos\RemoteControl\RemoteControl\RemoteControl.Host\Forms\ClientForm.cs:line 95
```

What could be causing this behavior? Shouldn't my code be getting into the `catch (FaultException<FaultBase> e)` block?

Foremost, how could I find the issue?

Edit:

I just discovered that the exceptions are being catched correctly, as long as the callback method returns void. It may have something to do with my callback setup.

Comment: Configure WCF to send error information. Use Fiddler to see what the server sent as a response. I guess that this is a serializer issue because the Exception type is not generally serializable.

Comment: I just discovered that the exception are being catches correctly, if the callback method returns void. It may have something to do with my callback setup.

Comment: My 2 cents: Have you try to catch(FaultException<GetSystemFilesFault> ex) ?
I think that a FaultException<GetSystemFilesFault> can not be casted into a FaultException<FaultBase>.